# Go flag: trailing slash escapes quote on Windows

Tags: regex, go

Need to validate and clean user input of a path. When a user enters the following command line:

```
 app.exe -f "C:\dir with space\"
```

The the flag value has the last quote escaped, so it's string value is:

```
 C:\dir with space"
```

What do you guys recommend for a clean approach at sanitizing user input for a directory/path?  Regex, or does Go have a library for dealing with this similar to filepath.Clean(), but removes trailing quote?

Edit: The cause is documented here:  https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16131

Comment: This is what I'm experiencing: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16131

Comment: I'd recommend your users learn their shell correctly, honestly. Your application can reasonably expect at least that of its users, especially a command-line application.

Comment: Escape the escapes? 
       `s = regexp.MustCompile(\`[\\]\`).ReplaceAllString(s,\`\$0\`)`

Comment: Don't try to be smarter than your users. Assume they meant what they said, and if that doesn't work tell them why. How do you know that my filename doesn't really end with a double quote?

Comment: But it's not what they intended. They intended to provide a dir that contains a space, but to do so, they are required to wrap it in quotes.  They didn't intend for the handoff between windows and golang to remove the first quote but keep the last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

func clean(path string) string {
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        path = strings.TrimSuffix(path, `"`)
    }
    return filepath.Clean(path)
}

func main() {
    path := `C:\dir with space"`
    fmt.Println(path)
    path = clean(path)
    fmt.Println(path)
}
```

Output:

```
C:\dir with space"
C:\dir with space
```

Reference: [MSDN: Windows: Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
 pkgDir   := flag.String( "f", "", "REQUIRED: `pkgdir` the root directory of the package")
 flag.Parse()

 *pkgDir = strings.TrimRight(*pkgDir, `'"`)
```